# Product Inquiry form in ubercart?

Tags: forms, ubercart

Can we provide an inquiry form for products in ubercart ? I want to provide a form to each product so that the user can send his/her requirement to site owner. Site owner can later on check who has contacted him and why. I do not want to provide add to cart option.

Comment: Yes, of course. To avoid this being closed as "Too broad", please edit your question to include a full description of what you're trying to accomplish, what methods you've already tried, and what specifically about those methods didn't work as you were expecting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a form in a block with a hidden field the captures the product name or information and then place the block wherever you want it.

Either store the information or just email it directly.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a form in a block with a hidden field the captures the product name or information and then place the block wherever you want it.
- Enable the below custom module(Replace form id with yours first).
- This custom module will work when you will check 'Show all webform pages in block ' from block configuration.
  By default multi-page webforms redirect to the node page for all pages after the first one. If checked, all pages will be shown in the block instead.

  ```
  function webform_nodevalues_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'webform-client-form-5') {
      if ($node = menu_get_object()) { 
        $form['submitted']['product_name']['#value'] = $node->title;
        $form['submitted']['my_webform_field_key']['#value'] = $node->my_cck_field[0]['value'];
      }
    }
  }
  ```